# IOS viewwilltransitiontosize method call all viewcontroller when rotate

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

My application has `Tabbar` and `Navigation` options. My problem is, when device is rotating to landscape, previous `viewcontroller` `viewwilltransitiontosize` is also calling

Let's explain the scenario,

The first screen is  AssignmentViewController
   The second screen is SubmissionListViewController

Both class I have override `viewwilltransitiontosize` method. when I rotate to landscape in the 2nd view controller time, it first calls `AssignmentViewController's viewwilltransitiontosize`  method then it calls `SubmissionListViewController's viewwilltransitiontosize`

here is my piece of code

```
     override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        self.landscapeVideo()
        self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = true
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        self.videoinPortraitMode()
        self.tabBarController!.tabBar.hidden = false
    }

}
```

any idea or help please?

Comment: Both your view controllers are loaded, so both will be notified of rotation changes. You could check if your view is actually visible before running any code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you figure this out?